# JavaScript function invoke

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have created an object as below in JS :

```
function test(){

  this.testParam1 = "add";

  this.tstMethod = function(){

  console.log("Hello")  ;   

 };

}

var testObj = new test();

console.log(assignTest.tstMethod());  ---> it prints value as undefined
console.log(assignTest.tstMethod);  ----> it prints the function
```

Could any one please explain me why can not we invoke `tstMethod`  as function?

Comment: But you do invoke it as a function...

Comment: What the heck is `assignTest`?

Comment: Apologies, I have missed to update  assignTest to testObj while copy pasting it from the local.

Answer (score 3):

Your object names don't match (`assignTest` vs `testObj`), but after correcting that, here's what's going on:

```js
function test() {
  this.testParam1 = "add";

  this.tstMethod = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
  };
}

var testObj = new test();

console.log(testObj.tstMethod());
console.log(testObj.tstMethod);
```

This will give the following output; note that `tstMethod` is being invoked correctly:

```
Hello                         // printed by tstMethod upon its invocation
undefined                     // the return value of tstMethod
this.tstMethod = function() { //
  console.log("Hello");       // the tstMethod function itself
};                            //
```

Comment: Hey Robby, thanks for your explanation, I missed to update the "testObj "while copy pasting it from the local.
But I was expecting "Hello" in the console when the method was invoked!!
May I know,why was not that happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal that your: `console.log(assignTest.tstMethod());` return `undefined` because your function does not return something it's only print something.

If you want this: `console.log(assignTest.tstMethod());` to return something, you should do inside your `tstMethod`function `return "Hello";` This would work.

Also `assignTest`is not defined, you should rename it to: `testObj`

Here's the code I make to test it out:

```
function test(){
    this.testParam1 = "add";
    this.tstMethod = function(){
        return "Hello";
    };
}

var testObj = new test();
console.log(testObj.tstMethod());
```

Hope I can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The `()` operator is what causes a function to be invoked. When you access a function without the `()` operator, *the function definition will be returned*. This is what is happening in your last console.log call.